# Deleting row by swipe not working propery in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swipe

I built an app using mvvm architecture. I don't know why
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`
it's not getting called on my view controller (basically swipe doesn't work, it can work like 1/20). If I build the tableview (basic one) with its methods to another view controller it works well. I tried to build one more time from scratch my view controller, but also it doesn't affect the result, so the problem is definitely in the functionality of the controller.

My code where swipe works well (I did that only to check if that works in my app:)

```
class tbViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    private var data = ["1","2","3","4"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self
    }
}
extension tbViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        return .delete
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

And my original view controller where swipe doesn't work, I also swapped original tableview with above one, only to verify if the problem is from tableview... I can't get it :C. (Please check first tableview methods) :

```
class ExpensesViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet private weak var thisWeek: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet private weak var thisMonth: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet private weak var thisYear: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet private weak var totalExpensedAmount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var pieChart: PieChartView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    private var menu: SideMenuNavigationController?
    private var tableViewActions = [Action]()
    private var expensesViewModel = ExpensesViewModel()
    private var data = ["1","2","3","4"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initSideBar()
        customizeButtons()
        customizePieChart()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapMenu(){
        present(self.menu!, animated: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func onClickThisWeek(_ sender: UIButton) {
        setGrayBackgroundAndBlackTitleColor(for: self.thisMonth, and: self.thisYear)
        sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.05509413034, green: 0.7074701786, blue: 0.4755263329, alpha: 1)
        sender.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
    
    @IBAction func onClickThisMonth(_ sender: UIButton) {
        setGrayBackgroundAndBlackTitleColor(for: self.thisWeek, and: self.thisYear)
        sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.05509413034, green: 0.7074701786, blue: 0.4755263329, alpha: 1)
        sender.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
    
    @IBAction func onClickThisYear(_ sender: UIButton) {
        setGrayBackgroundAndBlackTitleColor(for: self.thisWeek, and: self.thisMonth)
        sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.05509413034, green: 0.7074701786, blue: 0.4755263329, alpha: 1)
        sender.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
    
    private func setGrayBackgroundAndBlackTitleColor(for button1: UIButton, and button2: UIButton){
        button1.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.921431005, green: 0.9214526415, blue: 0.9214410186, alpha: 1)
        button2.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.921431005, green: 0.9214526415, blue: 0.9214410186, alpha: 1)
        button1.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button2.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1), for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
    
    
    private func initSideBar(){
        self.menu = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: MenuListController())
        self.menu?.leftSide = true
        self.menu?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = self.menu
        SideMenuManager.default.addPanGestureToPresent(toView: self.view)
    }
    
    private func customizeButtons(){
        self.thisWeek.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        self.thisWeek.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.05509413034, green: 0.7074701786, blue: 0.4755263329, alpha: 1)
        self.thisWeek.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.05509413034, green: 0.7074701786, blue: 0.4755263329, alpha: 1)
        self.thisMonth.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.05509413034, green: 0.7074701786, blue: 0.4755263329, alpha: 1)
        self.thisYear.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.05509413034, green: 0.7074701786, blue: 0.4755263329, alpha: 1)
    }
    
    private func customizePieChart(){
        self.pieChart.delegate = self
        self.pieChart.noDataText = "You don't have any income, to display quarters income."
        self.pieChart.legend.enabled = false
        let pieChartAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 16.0)!, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 0.462, green: 0.838, blue: 1.000, alpha: 1) ]
        let pieChartAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: "Quarterly Revenue", attributes: pieChartAttribute)
        self.pieChart.centerAttributedText = pieChartAttrString
    }
}


extension ExpensesViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        return .delete
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

How original screen should be:
[image]

How my screen is now, I commended basically all functionality to not confuse you, where my all business logic is, that's why nothing is displayed, it's just some UI changing, view model doesn't interact with controller(as you see in my code above):
[image]

If you have encountered such errors, please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/2902367-tableview

There’s also a similar function for leading swipes.

Answer (score 0):

"I don't know why
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` it's not getting called on my view controller".

The reason your method it is not getting called is that you forgot to add at the declaration of your view controller that it should be the  `UITableViewDelegate`.

Note: using [beginUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates) method is pointless to delete/remove a single row. Btw when doing multiple insertions/deletions better to use performBatchUpdastes. Last but not least, it is Swift naming convention to name your classes starting with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I didn't added 'UITableViewDelegate' protocol because, there are no need to implement methods that conform to this protocol. Btw I added, and it also doesn't work, that class was just for testing.

Comment: did you try `extension tbViewController: UITableViewDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource {`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate **• Respond to swipes and other actions in table rows.**

Comment: Yes... That was not the problem.
I have just found the error, I had implemented my sidemenu, with swipe from left to right. Basically, I think they are in conflict or smth with tableview swipe and it doesn't work properly. I just deleted init of sidemenu and it works perfect.
Also thanks a lot for your initiative.

Comment: You mean it was not the only problem. I dare your swipe to delete works without setting the view controller as the tableview delegate.